# How to access and use a dynamically created html element with IDs in the DOM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a To-Do App using plain vanilla JavaScript in which when a to-do(text) at the input field typed and added, the program dynamically creates two html elements ( a span and a button) and gives them attributes such as ID and event handlers, the span is where the to-do input text fall while a button will serve with the functionality of removing the input text by simply striking over the text.
Now when I try to create a button function for the button to strike the text It wont work.

Hire are my codes

html

```
<body>
<div>
    <h1>
        <span id="cls">3</span> To-DOs</h1>
    <input type="text" value="Enter A To-Do" id="input001" onclick="this.select()" onmouseout="this.style.transition = 0.5 + 's';"
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Insert" id="button" onmouseout="document.getElementById('button').style.transition = 0.5 + 's';"
     onclick="send()">
</div>
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your To-Do(s)</legend>
        <p id="import"> </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var get = document.getElementById('import');
    var no = 0;
    var click = 0;
    var input;
    var count = new Array("one", "two", "three");
    var count2 = new Array('a', 'b', 'c');
    var me = 0;

    document.getElementById('input001').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        // Enter Key Listener for the input box!
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (key == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            send();
        }
    })

    function send() {
        input = input001.value;

        if ((input == "Enter A To-Do") || (input == "")) {
            Alert.render("No To-Do Is Set!");
        } else if ((input != "Enter A To-Do") || (input != "")) {
            if (no <= 2) {
                click++;
                no++;

                var element = document.createElement('span');
                element.innerHTML = no + "  ." + input + "        ";
                element.id = count[me];

                var btnOne = document.createElement('button');
                btnOne.innerHTML = 'x';
                btnOne.id = count2[me];
                btnOne.setAttribute("onclick", "del()");

                window.elementTwo = element;
                window.btnTwo = btnOne;

                get.appendChild(elementTwo);
                get.appendChild(btnTwo);

                get.innerHTML += "<br />" + "<br />";
                input001.value = "";
                me++;
            } else if (no == 3) {
                Alert.render("Your 'To-Do Activity' input Limit On Your List Is Reached!" + "<br />" + "You Can't Add More! :(");
            }
        }
    }

    function del() {
        if(document.getElementById('a').clicked == true){

          document.getElementById('one').stike(); 

         }else if(document.getElementById('b').clicked == true){

           document.getElementById('two').stike();

    }else if(document.getElementById('c').clicked == true){

           document.getElementById('three').stike();
    }
}   

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So that is page, the codes aren't all of them, I have just highlighted the necessary parts, for Instance the Alert.render(); is my on custom alert box, so please don't mind that much since it has nothing to do with the codes.
*Any help: will be highly appreciated
*PS- please use a plain understandable and simple vanilla JavaScript, That's what is Know so Far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of changes:

1. You need to pass a parameter to the `del()` function.  In this
   case, I modified your code to pass the click event.  I then check the `id` of the clicked element in your if/else blocks.
2. `.strike()` is a `String` function, but you are applying it to a DOM element.  You need to grab the DOM text, apply `.strike()` to it, and set the `innerHTML` value to it.
3. `get` is a keyword in javascript, I changed it to get1.

```html
<body>
<div>
    <h1>
        <span id="cls">3</span> To-DOs</h1>
    <input type="text" value="Enter A To-Do" id="input001" onclick="this.select()" onmouseout="this.style.transition = 0.5 + 's';"
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Insert" id="button" onmouseout="document.getElementById('button').style.transition = 0.5 + 's';"
     onclick="send()">
</div>
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your To-Do(s)</legend>
        <p id="import"> </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var get1 = document.getElementById('import');
    var no = 0;
    var click = 0;
    var input;
    var count = new Array("one", "two", "three");
    var count2 = new Array('a', 'b', 'c');
    var me = 0;

    document.getElementById('input001').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        // Enter Key Listener for the input box!
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (key == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            send();
        }
    })

    function send() {
        input = input001.value;

        if ((input == "Enter A To-Do") || (input == "")) {
            Alert.render("No To-Do Is Set!");
        } else if ((input != "Enter A To-Do") || (input != "")) {
            if (no <= 2) {
                click++;
                no++;

                var element = document.createElement('span');
                element.innerHTML = no + "  ." + input + "        ";
                element.id = count[me];

                var btnOne = document.createElement('button');
                btnOne.innerHTML = 'x';
                btnOne.id = count2[me];
                btnOne.setAttribute("onclick", "del(event)");

                window.elementTwo = element;
                window.btnTwo = btnOne;

                get1.appendChild(elementTwo);
                get1.appendChild(btnTwo);

                get1.innerHTML += "<br />" + "<br />";
                input001.value = "";
                me++;
            } else if (no == 3) {
                Alert.render("Your 'To-Do Activity' input Limit On Your List Is Reached!" + "<br />" + "You Can't Add More! :(");
            }
        }
    }

    function del(ev) {
      
        if(ev.target.id == 'a'){

          document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = document.getElementById('one').innerText.strike(); 

         }else if(ev.target.id == 'b'){

           document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = document.getElementById('two').innerText.strike();

    }else if(ev.target.id == 'c'){

           document.getElementById('three').innerHTML = document.getElementById('three').innerText.strike();;
    }
}   

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You a lot for this answer, rely It was useful, and I have learned something useful from you through, please keep on that spirit!